# Does it make sense to check multiple hashes when detecting a file duplicate?

Tags: hashing, engineering

Please forgive me if this question belongs on different StackExchange site.

A much more experienced colleague (like, 8 times more experienced than me) has vigorously defended an idea that you should check multiple hash types (md5, sha1 etc.) *as well as size* to be absolutely sure that given file is not a duplicate of another.

I think it's BS and that it's enough to check the strongest hash used (though even md5 seems "strong enough" in this context). This already gives me more assurance than any weaker hash, so combining the two doesn't really add any benefits.

Am I right or wrong? I found multiple explanations that deal with crypto, but those aren't directly applicable.

Comment: *"to be absolutely sure that given file is not a duplicate of another"* - if the hashes are different, you can be absolutely sure the files are different, even if you use only one weak hash. What are you going to do if the hashes **are equal**? Will you then compare the files completely, byte by byte, or do you want to rely on those equal hashes to, for example, delete one of the two potential dupes?

Comment: Yeah, the purpose of this detection is to not store more than one copy of each file. If duplicate is detected, a link to existing copy is created.

Comment: @Red Even if an extremely strong hash shows that the files are "equal" it is no guarantee. You should compare the files byte-by-byte before concluding that they are duplicates. Since you are deleting data, you have to be 100% sure before you do it. Even if the hashes give you you 99.99999% confidence that they are the same, it is not good enough for the use case you've described.

Comment: @Brandin What if a cosmic ray flips a bit of RAM in your your code and negates the condition? Or you simply have a bug in your code? Both of these are *much* more likely than an accidental collision in SHA-2.

Comment: @CodesInChaos There will not likely be a bug if you test with two files that have the same hash. This is a simple test to do. Your program should say "files are not duplicate" and should not delete either of them. I don't know about cosmic rays. Is that testable? If not, forget about it.

Comment: @Brandin Bugs exist even in well test code and file systems are complex. RAM bitflips are happening in real life (one example http://dinaburg.org/bitsquatting.html) and the error correction in harddisks isn't infallable either. Whereas nobody has ever published even a single collision on SHA2 and the chances of it happening by accident are *extremely* small, so small that writing code to handle it is unnecessary.

Comment: You did not answer my question *Will you then compare the files completely, byte by byte, or do you want to rely on those equal hashes?*

Comment: If SHA1 is not enough, it's better to use a stronger hash rather than two hashes. Each additional hash just increases complexity with no benefit compared to just using a stronger hash.

Comment: If your data exceeds the hash width, there is at least one other data set that will collide. Hashes can only guarantee data difference; for sameness, a hash match means "a match is very likely" but there are no guarantees. If a very small probability of erroneous matching is okay, checking the widest hash you can get is fine. If the data is important, you must compare all data to guarantee accurate matching. For example: in [jdupes](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes) hashes are used for fast exclusions but full file hash matches are still compared byte-for-byte to avoid data loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Against accidental collisions, pretty much any decent hash with sufficient output size works. Even broken functions like MD5 (and soon SHA-1) are *very* unlikely to produce accidental collisions.

Against deliberate collisions concantenating multiple hashes gives you a hash as strong as the strongest individual. But probably not stronger than that.

It's generally better to upgrade to a stronger hash function rather than combining two weak hashes. I recommend SHA-2 and SHA-3 as collision resistant hashes. At 256+ bits, accidental collisions are so unlikely that you can completely ignore that possibility. And deliberate collisions are far beyond current publicly known cryptoanalysis.

SHA256 > MD5 + SHA1

Comment: Well, I'd say that any two "sufficiently different" cryptographic hashes used together gives you a stronger "actually the same" guarantee than either alone. To successfully defeat one or the other requires only a hash collision for one of the hashes, to successfully defeat both, you need to find a single document that is a collision for both.

Comment: @Vatine It depends on how the collision attacks work, but I don't expect a combined collision to be that much more difficult than breaking both hashes individually.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a 1 day experience, neither you nor your colleague can be considered as an expert in any domain. So "8 times" is not always an  impressive difference…

Hash functions transform an arbitrary input into a finite number. Since there is an infinite number of distinct inputs, there are "many" inputs that will be associated to the same output, whatever the hash function you consider. This is called a collision.

In your context, the question is therefore to determine the probability to accidentally obtain the same output for two distinct inputs. If the inputs are not maliciously chosen, the answer is that the probability is "very low". However, for some algorithms such as MD5, one consider that one can easily create an input having a predetermined output.

If you consider the output of several independent algorithms, the probability for a collision is the product of the probability of each algorithm: the outputs have to collide pairwise. This probability is therefore "extremely" small.

So if you don't suspect a malicious attack, the use of several "strong enough" algorithms is "better" (than the use of a single one) but also pointless.

You can refer to WP articles about hash functions. Git uses SHA-1 for identifying any version of any file it handles, and to prevent an accidental corruption of these files. As far as I know it doesn't cause any problem.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867191/probability-of-sha1-collisions) about the probability of a collision with SHA-1.

Comment: The security margin against deliberate SHA-1 collisions is becoming quite small, so I strongly recommend using using a stronger hash like SHA-2/3 instead.